# How to set an element center of view programmatically in iOS Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, layout, autolayout, constraints

I have a view and I want to center it horizontally and vertically in its superview.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
let horConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
view.addConstraints([horConstraint])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest trying to use *Anchors* which are more convenient and easy to understand. This code centered my view:

```
    let someView = UIView()
    someView.backgroundColor = .red
    someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(someView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        someView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        someView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        someView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        someView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
    ])
```

Comment: I used this with a Google **GIDSignInButton**.  Works great!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

Note: Make sure that you are setting this property (before applying constraints) to false for webView

```
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

For x axis

```
let horConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX ,multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
```

For y axis

```
let verConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY ,multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

view.addConstraints([horConstraint, verConstraint])
```